# Having conflict with certified translator about my transcript of records translation

Tags: computer-science, germany, transcript-of-records, translations, iran

I am a graduate in Computer Hardware Engineering who is trying to apply to a German university (for MSc). I think that the translator had some mistakes in translating my ToR, but he says that "I'm very experienced and my translation is faultless".

Which German translations are correct for these three academic subjects?
I think that my suggestions are more precise, but the translator insists on first ones and says that "your suggestions maybe correct, but don't exist as subjects in German universities":

En: **Computer Systems Architecture** (Fa: معماری سیستم‌های کامپیوتری):

- Translator: Computerarchitektur
- Me: Computersysteme Architektur

En: **VLSI Systems Design** (Fa: طراحی سیستم‌های وی‌ال‌اس‌آی):

- Translator: VLSI-Prozessentwurf
- Me: Design von VLSI-Systemen

En: **Programming Languages Design and Implementation** (Fa: طراحی و پیاده‌سازی زبان‌های برنامه‌سازی):

- Translator: Design u. Integrierung der Programmiersprachen
- Me: Design und Implementierung von Programmiersprachen

Comment: Does the translator know about the content of these courses or are they only depending on the titles for translation?

Comment: I am hesitant to say that Farsi-German translations are on-topic here, even if they are names of courses. Perhaps you'd get a better answer on the German StackExchange about whether they are well-formed in German?

Comment: I would find it unlikely that the German course names contain remnants of English. So I would expect _Rechnerarchitektur_ rather than anything containing "Computer", and _Entwurf_ instead of "Design". In fact, at the German university where I postdoc'd in the past, there was a course called _Rechnerarchitektur_, but this is purely anecdotal so it would be a bad fit for an answer.

Comment: @Buffy No, he is a general translator. The problem is that, just an unsuitable word can change the content of these courses, and it's the only official office in my city.

Comment: Now that the question is closed, I would edit to "I'm not sure my translator is doing a good job with my transcript, what should I do?" and remove the specific examples and I'd vote to reopn

Answer (score 3):

Introduction: All these documents will be screened by a computer program or at least by an university employee with scarce knowledge of the exams themselves. These screening procedures will have no consideration for context nor an in-depth knowledge of specific courses and subjects. An experienced person will know how these software works, and which kind of translations is required to get them working properly.

Translations, like medical exams evaluation, are a field where the individual expertise of the practitioner is highly needed. If you have no trust on the practitioner, go get a second opinion..
Costly? sure, but how much would an error cost? How much would you need to pay to retake the B.Sc exams you already did?

Then:

> The translator insists on first ones and says that "your suggestions
> maybe correct, but doesn't exist as a subject in German universities".

It means exactly that your translations are likely to be more precise, but less useful. If he is translating your document for your biography, then he is probably wrong.

If he is translating your document so the university receiving them can decide whether you need to retake an exam or not, then he is right. The issue is not the exact wording, it is the content of the courses. With the translator wording, maybe the universtity will require to provide you the topics of the course, to check if "course with same name has same contents".

If you go on with your wording, the university will probably decide "this exam has no correspondence with our exams", then the uni will provide you a list with topics you have to retake the exams ... and the list will contain "VLSI-prozessentwurf" because unfortunately you had knowledge only on "Design of VLSI-Systemen".

Good luck!